# Dominating a summoned creature

Tags: dnd-4e

I have a Sidhe House Guard adjacent to me, from the Summon Sidhe Ally power (Sidhe Lord Character Theme).

A Mind Flayer attacks and hits me, and I use the Immediate Interrupt power of my House Guard to have him get hit by the attack instead of me. One of the effects of the attack is Dominate (save ends).

How does this affect my House Guard, since he only takes Standard/Minor actions when I spend mine for him to do so, and he only moves when I move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dominated condition says that [the dominator chooses a single action for the creature to take on the creature’s turn](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=135). However, [a summoned creature has no actions of its own](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=85). So, a dominated summoned creature can't be controlled by the dominating creature simple because it is like dominating a stunned creature. You have control, but the creature can't act at all.

Since the Dominated condition also says that the creature can’t take actions voluntarily, I read that as you being incapable to giving your summoned creature orders as well, since the Summoning keyword says that you give it a command, not that you actually acts for the creature. This reading is a lot less clear, and DM-dependent.

It is also worthy saying that a Dominated creature also has other effects on it besides controlling its actions. So, it is still advantageous for the mindflayer to have your summon dominated.